# How can I get the application version with Frida? (Android)

Tags: android, frida

How can I get the application version? (Android)

[image]

```
frida -U -f it.subito -l '/path/to/get-app-version.js'
output: 6.39.4
```

Answer (score 2):

I bumped into a [Frida issue](https://github.com/frida/frida/issues/505) that solved my problem.

get-app-version.js

```
Java.perform(() => {

  const ActivityThread = Java.use('android.app.ActivityThread')
  const currentApplication = ActivityThread.currentApplication()
  const context = currentApplication.getApplicationContext()
  const pkgManager = context.getPackageManager()
  const pkgInfo = pkgManager.getPackageInfo(context.getPackageName(), 128)

  /* Don't work */
  // console.log('version: ', pkgInfo.versionName)
  // console.log('version: ', pkgInfo._versionName.value)

  console.log('version: ', pkgInfo.getClass().getField('versionName').get(pkgInfo))
})
```

First `console.log` prints:

```
version: [object Object]
```

Second one throws an error:

```
TypeError: cannot read property 'value' of undefined
    at <anonymous> (/frida/repl-2.js:23)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:12)
    at _performPendingVmOps (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:250)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:225)
    at <anonymous> (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/lib/vm.js:12)
    at _performPendingVmOpsWhenReady (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:244)
    at perform (frida/node_modules/frida-java-bridge/index.js:204)
    at <anonymous> (/frida/repl-2.js:26)
```

Third one works like a charm.

Unluckily I don't know why the short version `pkgInfo.versionName` doesn't work.

Comment: `pkgInfo._versionName.value` should work. The underscore is for safety reasons in case a method of the same name exists and the `.value` is required to get the actual value of the field (not the Frida JavaScript representation of the field).

Comment: @Robert unluckily doesn't work. Updated answer.